# How would you list your products on an e-commerce site?

Tags: mysql, database, web, e-commerce

A family member of mine is selling homemade soap, candles and reed diffusers.

There will be 3 different product categories, 8 different scents, with new scents being developed and added over the coming months.

What would be the most efficient (not easiest) way to setup product listings?

My HTML and CSS is ok and I'm currently learning C# and ASP so I primarily use Visual Studio.

Would it be best practice to learn and use an SQL database to store the products and then format them onto the website?

Should I just list the products on the page since there are only going to be a small number of products to start with?

Does using an SQL database make it easier when implementing a shopping cart?

I guess I just need to know how you would generally go about it so I know where to get started.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will only ever have 24 items and no need to track other kinds of data, then you can do whatever you want with your inventory list, including hard-coding your items. However, using a database *properly* can enable you to:

1. Add and modify items more easily.
2. Track inventory.
3. Track customer data.
4. Provide you with [ACID guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).
5. Provide you with [normalized data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

So yes, you can hard-code your inventory, or use a non-database backend store like YAML or PStore, but it simply will not scale well. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

With e-commerce, if you just started. It is easier, if you get widely used framework.

Most of them will have e-commerce plug in, for example, Joomla, Wordpress, or Silverstripe.

It easy to start, and you just need to modify the layout template.